# Confusion on Summation Notation in Lagrange's Identity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation, notation

I'm working on a proof (the proof of Lagrange's Identity), but it includes a sum notation I'm not familiar with:

$$\sum_{1\le k\lt j\le n} (a_kb_j-a_jb_k)^2$$

I would appreciate any explanations of what this is saying, specifically in regards to the inequalities below the sigma.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This means you are summing the value of $(a_kb_j-a_jb_k)^2$ over all ordered pairs $(k,j)$ such that $1\leq k<j\leq n$.  For instance, if $n=3$, these ordered pairs are $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, and $(2,3)$, so the sum is $$(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)^2+(a_1b_3-a_3b_1)^2+(a_2b_3-a_3b_2)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

The notation is indeed confusing. It should be $$\sum_{\substack{k,j \\1\leq k<j\leq n}}$$ i.e., summing over $k$ and $j$ with the condition given below.

Answer (score 2):

${1\leq j<k\leq n}$ is the domain of the operator.   We sum the terms for all integer values of the bound variables, $(j,k)$, where this domain holds true.

This is *sometimes* more convenient than the double sum notation with which you might be more familiar.
$$\sum_{1\leq j<k\leq n} (a_k b_j −a_j b_k )^2
\\ ~=~ \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n}(a_k b_j −a_j b_k )^2 
\\ ~=~ \sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(a_k b_j −a_j b_k )^2 $$

Answer (score 0):

For example, $1 \le k < j \le 5$ would indicate the $(j,k)$ pairs

\begin{array}{cccc}
   (2,1) \\
   (3,1) & (3,2) \\
   (4,1) & (4,2) & (4,3) \\
   (5,1) & (5,2) & (5,3) & (5,4)
\end{array}